# Icones maiores que a caixa de texto

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

[image: icones no layout grandes demais!]

Como diminuo o tamanho desses icones no meu layout?

Answer (score -1):

Se calhar era melhor por `ImageView` e `EditText` dentro de um `LinearLayout` com orientação horizontal

Comment: porque a votação negativa?